# How to identify using a regular expression a specific string written over two lines within a text?

Tags: regex, string, vbscript

Please, how would I identify using a vbs regular expression a specific string within a text knowing that the first part of the searched string is on a line and the second on the following line?

I have tested unsuccessfully many expressions, for example

```
\*[A-Z]{8}; \*[A-Z]{3}\n[A-Z]{5}
```

Example: In the text below, I need to retrieve the string `*ZKVDMGER`:

```
K MAT NSA7143*USA 3 AIRLINES TOWN LOSA20 09:30AM 10:30PM ED  S    *ZKV
   DMGER
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know at which part the string will be split? Is there only a newline character at the split or possibly also other whitespace?

Comment: both of them are possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `\S+\r?\n\S+`

- `\S+` : match non whitespace characters one or more times
- `\r?\n` : match newlines in windows/linux
- `\s*` : match whitespaces zero or more times
- `\S+` : match non whitespace characters one or more times

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mW3jS0)

Comment: It doesn't work right. Indeed, the second part of string is preceded by some spaces or tab

Comment: This expression is to large because in my context, it matchs others strings which are not concerned. I'm based on your answer to write "\*[A-Z]{3}\r?\n\s*[A-Z]{5}" in order to match exactly the example embedded in my question. Nevertheless  it is not working. Do you know please how could i reduce targets for my example?. Thank you in advance

Comment: @new Well this answer is based on your first post (when you didn't provide a regex, at least I somehow didn't see it). Without any further examples on what you want to match and what not and without explaining the "other requirements", I shall only point you to Tim's expression.

Comment: I thank you all. I have modified the Tim's expression as \*[A-Z]{8}|\*[A-Z]{3}\s*\n\s*[A-Z]{5} and that's ok. Sorry what I didn't see  is that additionnal whitespaces may precede the newline. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct alternation operator: `|`, not `;`. Also, if additional whitespace may follow the newline break, you need to account for that, too:

```
\*[A-Z]{8}|\*[A-Z]{3}\n\s*[A-Z]{5}
```

Comment: I note that it doesn't work because the count property returns no strings that matches.

Comment: @new and I prove to you that the expression [*does* work](http://regex101.com/r/zL7tL1). Please fix your code instead.